# $(X^Y)^Z\sim X^{Y\times Z}$

Tags: functions, relations, products

I'm trying to prove the equipotency of these two sets.
I know I have to find an invertible function $f:(X^Y)^Z\rightarrow X^{Y\times Z}$ between the two sets.

Which means I have to find a function $g:X^{Y\times Z}\rightarrow (X^Y)^Z$ such that:
\begin{align}
    f\circ g (h)&=h \quad \text{for any } h\in X^{Y\times Z}\quad \text{and}\\
    g\circ f (k)&=k \quad \text{for any } k\in (X^Y)^Z
\end{align}
Now I can note that
\begin{align}
    h:Y\times Z&\longrightarrow X\\
    (y,z)&\longmapsto h(y,z)\\
    \\ 
    k:Z&\longrightarrow X^Y\\
    z&\longmapsto k(z):Y\rightarrow X\\
    &\qquad\qquad\quad\text{ } y\mapsto k(z)(y)
\end{align}
Does this help me in any way?

I'm clueless as to what to pay attention to in order to reach that, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It might be easier to show that the map $g: X^{Y\times Z}\to (X^Y)^Z$ given by $g:F\mapsto \left(z\mapsto \left(y\mapsto F(y,z)\right)\right)$ is 1--1 and onto.

Comment: So for injectivity it would be sort of: if $g(F)=g(G)\Rightarrow F=G$ and do $g(F(y,z))=g(G(y,z)) \Leftrightarrow F(z)(y)=G(z)(y) \Rightarrow F=G$.   

And for surjectivity it would be like: $\forall F' \in (X^Y)^Z$, $\exists F\in X^{Y\times Z}, g(F)=F'$ and given that $F'=F'(z)(y)$ for some $z\in Z$ and $y\in Y$, then we could just make $g(F(y,z))=F'(z)(y)$. 

Does this suffice?

Comment: I don't think that what you have written makes sense: $g$ doesn't apply to values $F(y,z)\in X$ it applies to functions, ie elements of $X^{Y\times Z}$; you can't one moment write $F(y,z)$ and the next write $F(z)(y)$, and you can't write $F'=F'(z)(y)$.  Doing set theory at this level means you must be much more careful.

Comment: Yeah okay, i kept thinking to myself that this is a very naïve thing to do, thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maps $f\colon (X^Y)^Z\to X^{Y\times Z}$ and $g\colon X^{Y\times Z}\to (X^Y)^Z$  may look somewhat convoluted, but are after all natural (also in the technical sense):
If $\phi\in (X^Y)^Z$, i.e., $\phi$ is a map $Z\to X^Y$, then for every $z\in Z$, $\phi(z)$ is an element of $X^Y$, i.e., a map $Y\to X$. In order to define $f(\phi)$, we need to exhibit a map $Y\times Z\to X$. The - indeed natural - candidate is given by
$ \langle y,z\rangle\mapsto \phi(z)(y).$
So to summarize,
$$ f\colon \phi\mapsto (\langle y,z\rangle\mapsto \phi(z)(y))$$
Similarly, given $\psi\in X^{Y\times Z}$, i.e., $\psi\colon Y\times Z\to X$, $g$ shall map this to a map from $Z$ to the set of maps from $Y$ to $X$. The -again natural - candidate is to let $g(\psi)$ map $z$ to the map $Y\to X$ given by $y\mapsto \psi(\langle y,z\rangle)$. To summrize again,
$$ g\colon \psi\mapsto (z\mapsto(y\mapsto \psi(\langle y,z\rangle))).$$
As the definitions of $f,g$ were natural, we expect $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ to be natural as well - and what could be more natural as map from $(X^Y)^Z$ (or $X^{Y\times Z}$) to itself than the identity? Wll, we have to check nevertheless:
For $\phi\in (X^Y)^Z$,
$$ \begin{align}(g\circ f)(\phi)&=g(f(\phi))\\&=g(\underbrace{\langle y,z\rangle\mapsto\phi(z)(y)}_{=:\psi})\\
&=(z\mapsto (y\mapsto \psi(\langle y,z\rangle)))\\
&=(z\mapsto(y\mapsto \phi(z)(y)))\\
&=(z\mapsto \phi(z))\\&=\phi\end{align}$$
and vice versa for $\psi\in X^{Y\times Z}$,
$$\begin{align}(f\circ g)(\psi)
&=f(g(\psi))\\
&=f(\underbrace{z\mapsto(\underbrace{y\mapsto\psi(\langle y,z\rangle)}_{=:\chi})}_{=:\phi})\\
&=(\langle y,z\rangle\mapsto \phi(z)(y))\\
&=(\langle y,z\rangle\mapsto \chi(y)\\
&=(\langle y,z\rangle\mapsto \psi(\langle y,z\rangle))\\
&=\psi\end{align} $$

Comment: oh my god im so stupid, so I understood where the mappings went and what they meant i drew them multiple times to see if i was missing something, i just didn't know how to proceed and NEVER thought of plugging $\phi$ into $f$ or $\psi$ into $g$ and leaving it represented as a map. That notation helps tremendously thank you so much ;_;